# How to count filtered data when using slicer in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-filter

[image: Data After slicer]

The sheet above shows data filtered by using Slicer.

**How can I count rows when I filter data by a column using the slicer?**

Let's say I want the counted result to appear in cell L4. If I use the `counta()` function, it still counts all rows instead of the filtered rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the `SUBTOTAL` function

```
=SUBTOTAL(3,A6:A)
```

[image]

Functions used:

- [`SUBTOTAL`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093649)